# SQL Server Agent Job - Export results to Tab Delimited File?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I setup a SQL server agent job that runs a stored procedure at a specific time.  Once the stored procedure is done running, how can I export the results to a Tab Delimited file?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have xp_cmdshell enabled and if your account has access you could try:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM tblName" queryout "C:\tblNameData.txt" -T -c
```

Another way is to do it as @Neil mentioned: SSIS. Here's a link:

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/ssis-exporting-data-to-a-text-file-using-a-package/

Comment: I think the BCP will end up being the route I go with

Comment: @broke , if that's the case then you can check this link out for a simple bcp approach you can start with: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/

Answer (score 4):

For this specific task, I would use SSIS, purely for its ease.

[`bcp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is another alternative using a [file format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx).

Comment: I have never used SSIS before.  Is there another approach?