# confusion with quotes and double quotes in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

i have a query that works  beautifully:

```
CREATE Procedure BCP_Text_File
(  
    @table varchar(100),  
    @FileName varchar(100)  
)  
AS
    If exists(Select * from information_Schema.tables where table_name=@table)
    Begin
        Declare @str varchar(1000)  
        set @str='Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell ''bcp "Select * from '+db_name()+'..'+@table+'" queryout "'+@FileName+'" -c'''  
        Exec(@str)  
    end
    else
        Select 'The table '+@table+' does not exist in the database'
```

but i need to add this in there:

```
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = @table
order by ordinal_position
```

so far i have:

```
   alter Procedure BCP_Text_File
   (  
      @table varchar(100),  
      @FileName varchar(100)  
    )  
    AS 
       If exists(Select * from information_Schema.tables where table_name=@table)
       Begin
           Declare @str varchar(1000)  
           set @str='Exec Master..xp_Cmdshell ''bcp "

           select column_name 
           from information_schema.columns
           where table_name = '+db_name()+'..'+@table+'
           order by ordinal_position

           Select * from '+db_name()+'..'+@table+'" queryout "'+@FileName+'" -c'''  
           Exec(@str)  
       end
       else
           Select 'The table '+@table+' does not exist in the database'
```

but i think i am missplacing the single quotes and/or double quotes. i am adding this select statement so that my result has the field names as the first row.

thanks so much for any help or guidance.

Comment: Debugging 101: change `EXEC(@str)` to `PRINT(@str)`

Comment: Are those `'..'` actually in the query?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i'm sorry i am unable to ALTER it. i cant compile it

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this? You can debug better if you pull the code *out* of the stored procedure. Then compilation won't prevent you from seeing where the problems are. If you have IntelliSense enabled they might even make themselves obvious.

Comment: I believe this stems from the answer on your other question. Since you would like this automated, may I recommend that you move away from the SSMS requirement and create a SQL Agent job? There are quite a few resources (including [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238230/sql-server-csv-exports-using-sql-server-agent-powershell) and [this](http://thebakingdba.blogspot.com/2011/04/invoke-sqlcmd-query-select-getdate.html) and [this](http://poshcode.org/1662))

Comment: ... or SSIS (which accepts parameters into local and global variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want? This assumes that (a) none of your column names have commas in them, and (b) the output of each column, when implicitly converted to a string, is okay.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.BCP_Text_File
    @table    NVARCHAR(255),  
    @filename VARCHAR(100)  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF OBJECT_ID(@table) IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @cols += ',' + name
      FROM sys.columns
      WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table)
      ORDER BY column_id;

    SELECT @cols = STUFF(@cols, 1, 1, '');

    SET @sql = N'EXEC master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT ''''' 
        + REPLACE(@cols, ',', ''''',''''') + ''''' UNION ALL SELECT ' 
        + 'RTRIM(' + REPLACE(@cols, ',', '),RTRIM(') + ') FROM ' 
        + DB_NAME() + '..' + @table + '" queryout "' + @filename + '" -c''';  
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'The table '+@table+' does not exist in the database';
  END
END
GO
```

But I have to agree with the advice you've gotten from others on this and other questions - this approach is very brittle. You're trying to crack open a pistachio with a steamroller.

PS I removed references to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, because I think [the catalog views are more reliable and more consistent](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: thank you so much you are a treasure, however getting this error: User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name or use -T for Trusted Connection

Comment: Suggest you get a basic BCP command working first. As the error message suggested, if you're not connected to the server using a default instance and an account that has the ability to launch bcp and log back in, you'll need to add parameters such as -U/-P or -T.

Comment: i got it working by putting the -T in there thanks so much; however, i looked at the file and it did not put any commas, just spaces as delimitteres

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation for BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)? At all? Come on. Like I suggested before, get a *SIMPLE* BCP command working the way you want first. I'll give you a hint: you need to specify something different for `-t` - the default is a tab.